# How can I refactor this Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I have the following in my controller:

```
@custom_exercises = @user.exercises.all
@all_exercises = Exercise.not_the_placeholder_exercise.public.order("name").all

if @user.trainers.present?
  trainer_exercises = []
  @user.trainers.each do |trainer|
    trainer_exercises << trainer.exercises.all
  end
  @my_trainer_custom_exercises = trainer_exercises
end

@exercises = @custom_exercises + @all_exercises

if @my_trainer_custom_exercises.present?
  @exercises << @my_trainer_custom_exercises
  @exercises.flatten!
end
```

This feels really messy. How could I refactor this?

Comment: You may want to checkout the [CodeReview Stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step: set up an AR relationship between users and exercises, probably along the lines of:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trainer_exercises,
             :through => :trainers,
             :foreign_key => :client_id,
             :source => :exercises
end
```

Second step: move `@all_exercises` to a class method in `Exercise`.

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_exercises
    not_the_placeholder_exercise.public.order("name").all
  end
end
```

This way, the whole controller gets a whole lot simpler:

```
@custom_exercises = @user.exercises.all
@trainer_exercises = @user.trainer_exercises.all
@exercises = Exercise.all_exercises + @custom_exercises + @trainer_exercises
```

Comment: +1 for answering all the way through and taking advantage of AR and such.  Beat me to the punch :)

Comment: I'm getting a stack level too deep when I try this. I think it's because user/trainer are the same model perhaps? How can I handle this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2092757d2e84b803ef44

Comment: Also the user could have multiple trainers, so how do you grab each one's custom exercises?

Comment: I updated my answer, should be fine now. I set up a test application and got it to work. If you use the right associations, you won't need to loop through each user's trainers to get each one's exercises because you'll be offloading this work to your database.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely less lines of code perspective, you could start with this ( more or less / not tested but should work:

```
if @user.trainers.present?
  @my_trainer_custom_exercises = @user.trainers.each.inject([]){ |trainer, trainer_exercises| 
    trainer_exercises << trainer.exercises.all 
  }
end
```

Comment: `.each.inject([])` == `.map`